# Parsing json to a string in Gson

Tags: java, json, gson, realm

I have a json string:

```
 {  
   "id":123,
   "name":"",
   "details":{}
}
```

I want to parse to this object:

```
class Student {

int id;
String name; 
String details;

}
```

This is the error that I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xxx.xxx/xxx.xxx.MainActivity}: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected STRING but was BEGIN_OBJECT
```

The reason I want details as string not as a JsonObject because I'm using Realm DB object and persist that to the database. How can I tell Gson I want the `details` as string.

Comment: Your "json" isn't actually JSON - the field names aren't in quotes. It should be `{ "id": 123, "name": "", "details": {} }`. That *may* be all that's wrong. It would help if you'd show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, mind you...

Comment: You can take the JSON Object and convert it to JSON String before saving in DB if you are question is with respect to only "details" attribute.

Comment: `"details":{}` not compatible with `String details;` (that's what the error is telling you. It expects a String, but finds an Object, and bam.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a nice way to solve it but currently I copy the json object and stringify it to variable, remove it from the json element and then call gson fromJson.

Answer (score 1):

The `details` value, `{}`, is an object not a string.  It will not be interpreted as a string unless you quote it like this:

```
{
"id":123,
"name":"",
"details":"{}"
}
```

GSON is telling you "`Expected STRING but was BEGIN_OBJECT`".  This makes sense, because you're giving it a type signature with a `String` attribute named `details`, but your serialization has an attribute named `details` that contains an empty object.

Comment: Thanks, my fault. This is just an example, didn't want to share internal details. I'll fix the example.

Comment: Alright.  I'll add details to help with the actual problem then.

Comment: @Jimmy: when posting a question, post input and code that actually demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @njzk2 I did, I had a mistake in the example I provided and fixed it. But I understand your comment.

Comment: @Jimmy, I think he meant the GSON calling code, specifically.  Did my answer work for you?